# Private network establishment with static nodes using geth client

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I am setting up a private network using geth by the method static- nodes. I have created the `static nodes.json` file with 4 enodes and put it in the `/usr/local/cellar/test2/geth/static-nodes.json`. In terminal when I'm running the console command I getting an error:

`ERROR[11-06|10:11:33] Can't load node file /usr/local/Cellar/test2/geth/static-nodes.json: JSON syntax error at /usr/local/Cellar/test2/geth/static-nodes.json:4: invalid character '\n' in string literal`.

Plz find me a path to setup the permanent peers to setup private network
My `static-nodes.json` is

```
[
"enode://dc3e4f23315f90bb62c9096df01b7f07c4040a8520f046801e2fa6812aa4402d70f6073f6226779a9183137cb789e98492d197db1380784fd0d213c30e9651ec@192.168.1.139:30331",
"enode://1c745b2459129ca07b1345487fedda6b8516194a4208d93bd696f3684b44cbf16a5cdddb99cc1753b1ba43884d93c5d27403dce0c6638787f74a40428a7c9543@192.168.1.117:30332”,
"enode://be0c22a7a8451766c2894cd11143bc3128d5840cca161ad91b2bd9078d1dde56ddc19d0258e86e51cf7b7e9cda43b900a20ef392925ae8a19ab24c4cf016d69c@192.168.1.121:30333”,
"enode://1e07a29f0c94617d045dcf4f0d8597fd07757cbf8e48f66e78b72b142bf9b61d0d7bcce8fe21479ad0bd02bff945a8c062f2af03c0e1be670e1452b845fa420e@192.168.1.102:30334"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

From the static-nodes.json file you have provided the double-quotes at the end of lines 3 and 4 look different to the double quotes on lines 2 and 5. This may be a character encoding issue, maybe edit the file and delete the double quotes and type them again. Just an observation.

There are online json syntax validators that can help you find the issue such as https://jsonlint.com/